# Iterating through a List of Lists and calling variables explicitly

Tags: python, list, if-statement

Below is a small snip of the list of lists that I am currently working with.

```
[(datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 27, 17, 33, 1), 'derivative', 74L, 980750911L, 150.
49), (datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 27, 17, 33, 1), 'other', 211L, 2519735424L, 383
.99), (datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 27, 17, 33, 1), 'source', 9L, 68556768874L, 31
27.9)]
```

Now, my end game goal is iterating through this list of lists to separate values so I can write them to an excel file. My issue is the separation of the values. For example I know how to print out all the values of each value in the list of lists with this

```
for x in data:
    for x in x:
        print x
```

The return format is as so after that is executed.

```
2014-06-28 21:50:54
source
27
14144158722
1425.26
```

Now, how can I call on one specific value in that return, for example if I wanted to make an if statement that only printed out x in the list of lists if the x had source in its content. I tried to explain this thoroughly, ready to provide any clarification.

Comment: try using in operator to check if inner list contains source, if true print

Comment: couldn't you just `filter` your list: `sources = filter(lambda el: el[1] == 'source', data)`. Now `sources` contains all the elements where the 2nd entry was `'source'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the `if` statement before iterating into the inner list, so that you only iterate when the `if` condition is satisfied.

Also, you shouldn't be doing - `for x in x` , it is confusing.

Example -

```
>>> data = [(datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 27, 17, 33, 1), 'derivative', 74, 980750911, 150.49), (datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 27, 17, 33, 1), 'other', 211, 2519735424, 383.99), (datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 27, 17, 33, 1), 'source', 9, 68556768874, 3127.9)]
>>> for x in data:
...     if 'source' in x:
...             for y in x:
...                     print y
...
2015-07-27 17:33:01
source
9
68556768874
3127.9
```

Comment: That is almost perfect for what I need. That currently returns ```2014-06-28 21:50:54
source
27
14144158722
1425.26``` But what if I only what to call the first value,2014-06-28 21:50:54 or the second value. Would I do print y[0], I know that does not work but hopefully you get what I am saying

Comment: Then do not use an inner list, just directly get the value you need by indexing it - Example `x[0]` would give the date, `x[1]` would give the second value

Comment: Now if I am using xlsxwriter and I have predefined headers Source Date and Source Gowth. Using the example value (datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 27, 17, 33, 1), 'source', 9, 68556768874, 3127.9). If I want to write date to Date in the excel file how would I execute that

Comment: From documentation given [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XlsxWriter) , Most probably you would do - for date - `worksheet.write(<row>,<column>,x[0])` - for growth - `worksheet(<row>,<column>,x[1])` .

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't re-use the name `x` in your inner loop; use descriptive names. You can test for containment in the outer loop:

```
for row in data:
    if 'source' in row:
        for column in row:
            print column
```

You probably want to limit this to a specific column however; each of your rows have a specific structure, each column carries one type of data; the first column is a date, the second column is the string you want to test against:

```
for row in data:
    if row[1] == 'source':
        for column in row:
            print column
```

You could just *unpack* your rows into separate variables:

```
for timestamp, type_, num1, num2, num3 in data:
    if type_ == 'source':
        print timestamp
        print num1
        print num2
        print num3
```